# Why is couchdb installed?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, couchdb

I don't recall installing a couchdb package.  What other packages may have installed this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UbuntuOne needs CouchDB for contacts and notes synchronisation.

Comment: Well that would explain it.